# Library not found for -lFlipper-Boost-iOSX

Tags: react-native

An error appeared after updating some software.

```
> Library not found for -lFlipper-Boost-iOSX
```

Flipper version:

```
> use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.100.0', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.6.7' })
```

What seems to be the issue, and how may I fix this?